# How can I fix broken images in Ubuntu 20.04 when served over HTTP instead of HTTPS?

Tags: apache2

I am getting the below sample HTTP headers inserted at the top of image files (jpg, png) when they are served by Apache2 using HTTP. When I load a web page that contains images the browser(Chrome, FireFox, Edge) show a broken link. When I try to down the images they do download however the HTTP header info can be seen in the file. If I load them with HTTPS the images display fine.  How can I get the images to also serve under HTTP?  This is a newly upgraded development machine.  I also rebuilt a new VM using Ubuntu 20.04 and have the same issue.  I am using a self signed cert for SSL and this causes other issues because it is not fully trusted.

---

```
 22:27:40 GMT
ETag: "b747-57618ae5a4f00"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 46919
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: image/png
```

[image: Config Files]

Comment: Looks like something splits the HTTP header and one part gets attached at the beginning of image data. That's probably the reason why the images can't be displayed. You need to find what and why is cutting off these headers.

Comment: You want the web server to provide content for both HTTP and HTTPS requests? If so, can you include the Apache virtual host config file for the site? This will make it much easier to offer a specific answer rather than guessing at how access and redirects might already be configured.

Comment: Yes both HTTP and HTTPS.  I attached an image of the files.